# Wrap Block In Container

Tags: magento2, default.xml

I am including the extension **`Ves MegaMenu`** in my theme in **`default.xml`**.
How can I wrap this within a container?

```
<referenceBlock name="page.wrapper">
    <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="catalog.topnav" after="header.container" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml">
        <arguments> 
            <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">menu-top</argument> 
        </arguments> 
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

---

```
<container name="my.container" label="My Wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass=""/> <!-- declare your new container-->           
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="my.container"  after="page.wrapper"  /> <!-- move  your desire block to your new container-->
```

---

After that do cache refresh.

Comment: It doesn't seem to display when I use the above code.
I actually have a container I can put it in "navigation.sections". I've tried the following but it doesn't display:

`<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="navigation.sections" after="-"/>`

Any ideas? Thanks